VCCLCompilerTool Object of DTE Automation does not appear to have a MultiProcessorCompilation flag
I'm working with a VS2003 style .net Project wizard in VS2019.
Inside the default.js Add Config option there is this code:
var CLTool   = config.Tools('VCCLCompilerTool');
             // TODO: Add compiler settings
var bMPFlag  = wizard.FindSymbol('MP_FLAG');
var bPCHFlag = wizard.FindSymbol('PRE_COMPILED_HEADER_FLAG');
if (bMPFlag) {
  //CLTool.AdditionalOptions.concat(' /MP');  // Expect this line works
  //CLTool.AdditionalOptions='/MP8';          // This line works
  //CLTool.MultiProcessorCompilation=true;    // Property does not exist
} else {
  //CLTool.AdditionalOptions.replace('/MP',''); // Expect this line works
  //CLTool.AdditionalOptions='/MP1';            // This line works
  //CLTool.MultiProcessorCompilation=false;     // Property does not exist
}

I can set the Additional Compile Options to include /MP or /MP1 /MP8, but inside the default project there is a MultiprocessorCompilation property which sets the default /MP to on.
I want to be able to optionally disable the /MP flag and I can't seem to make this happen :(
There is no property MultiProcessorCompilation in the VCCLCompilerTool Interface.
The only way to make this work is to hack the default project to eliminate the /MP and insert /MP or don't insert /MP in Additional Options.  I was hoping for some way in the AddConfig function of default.js to make this work.
Just wonder if I am missing anything.
I'm able to enable/disable pre-compiled headers fine with the .UsePrecompiledHeader property, but there is no MultiProcessorCompilation property that will overide the properties setting in the default project.  Was hoping there was some way to do that.
<ClCompile>
  <PrecompiledHeader>Use</PrecompiledHeader>
  <PreCompiledHeaderFile>tester.h</PreCompiledHeaderFile>
  <!--<MultiProcessorCompilation>true</MultiProcessorCompilation>-->
  <DebugInformationFormat>ProgramDatabase</DebugInformationFormat>
</ClCompile>

My desired solution would like to have <MultiProcessorCompilation> property set to true in the project (default-x64.vcxproj) and disable the property based on user input via HTML.
When I use AdditionalOptions the MSBuild/VS property is not set so it looks like /MP is not set when it actually is.  Perhaps what I need is a way to set an MSBUILD property via the JavaScript.

Well The way I resolved this was the following.
Early in the wizard I select either a Win32 or X64 project.
This is in the CreateCustomProject function.
Here I can access my symbol MP_FLAG which is true (multi process compile) or false (no multi process compile).
Here I have a statement
var strProjX64 = (bMPFlag == true)? 'default-x64_MP.vcxproj':'default-x64_noMP.vcxproj';  // Only way to do this

And if it's /MP I use Project with :
<ClCompile>
  <PrecompiledHeader>Use</PrecompiledHeader>
  <PreCompiledHeaderFile>blah.h</PreCompiledHeaderFile>
  <MultiProcessorCompilation>true</MultiProcessorCompilation>
  <DebugInformationFormat>ProgramDatabase</DebugInformationFormat>
</ClCompile>

If its not /MP I use the project with
<ItemDefinitionGroup>
  <ClCompile>
    <PrecompiledHeader>Use</PrecompiledHeader>    
    <PreCompiledHeaderFile>blah.h</PreCompiledHeaderFile>
    <!--<MultiProcessorCompilation>true</MultiProcessorCompilation>-->
    <DebugInformationFormat>ProgramDatabase</DebugInformationFormat>
  </ClCompile>
</ItemDefinitionGroup>

The PreCompiledHeader flag I can control later in the default.js with:
function AddConfig(proj, strProjectName) 
  {
  try
    {
    var config              = proj.Object.Configurations('Debug');
        config.useOfMfc     = useOfMfc.useMfcDynamic;
        config.CharacterSet = charSetMBCS;
    
    // AddPlatform("x64");
    
    var CLTool   = config.Tools('VCCLCompilerTool');
                 // TODO: Add compiler settings
    var bPCHFlag = wizard.FindSymbol('PRE_COMPILED_HEADER_FLAG');

    if (bPCHFlag) 
      {
      CLTool.UsePrecompiledHeader = 2;   // This is working
      } 
    else 
      {
      CLTool.UsePrecompiledHeader = 0;   // This is working
      }
  //...

This allowed me to have /MP = ON and Precompiled Headers = on as the default wizard setting but allow users to disable this if they desire, which will create the correct C++ project.

CLTool.UsePrecompiledHeader = bPCHFlag ? 2 : 0;

also var strProjX64 = bMPFlag ? 'default-x64_MP.vcxproj':'default-x64_noMP.vcxproj';  testing a boolean value to get a boolean value is nonsens...
